# How to deploy PKI in Azure using JSON template (windows server)

Tags: json, azure, pki

I'm new to Azure.
I have JSON template that successfully deploys VM.
Can I add some code to JSON template to deploy this VM with rootCA. Or some syntax for AD CS deployment.
I googled a lot but there are only DSC methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add some code to JSON template".
Your options:

1. Native ARM via Keyvault:
   https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/875d139c16c9c023dce519e6dd48c707e3473346/201-vm-push-certificate-windows/azuredeploy.json
2. Add an extention to the ARM template.
   An extention can be DSC as you mentioned, but can also be custom PowerShell for example. (see [custom script extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows/azuredeploy.json))
3. Run your script after the deployment. If you run New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment form PowerShell, you can output the VM connection information, and manage it after. See how to [configure WinRM on a created VM](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/f95cef95773a2ed03fd84bf5cdb9240d29bc9914/201-vm-winrm-windows).